# Magento 2 product gallery doesn't close on iPhone

Tags: magento2, product, gallery, fotorama

I'm using Magento 2.2.1, with a theme that has magento blank theme as parent. I'm having a problem on iPhone 6, but not on Windows mobile or Android. Basically when I go on the product page, and open the product gallery images, I can't close the gallery anymore when I press the X, as I sayd, this happens only on iPhone. The gallery used is a Fotorama, is the default one, anyone has any idea what it might be?

Comment: Hi @alexcr same issue i am facing in Magento2.2.3 CE did u fix this? please advise

Answer (score 7):

Override `fotorama.js` in your custom theme at `app/design/<vendor>/<custom_theme>/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`, you can copy this file from `\lib\web\fotorama\fotorama.js` and replace code as per below at line no. 1220

From

```
function stubEvent($el, eventType) {
    $el.on(eventType, function (e) {
        stopEvent(e, true);

        return false;
    });
}
```

To

```
function stubEvent($el, eventType) {
     var isIOS = /iP(ad|hone|od)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);

    if (isIOS && eventType === 'touchend') {
        $el.on('touchend', function(e){
            $DOCUMENT.trigger('mouseup', e);
        })
    }

    $el.on(eventType, function (e) {
        stopEvent(e, true);

        return false;
    });
}
```

**Note:** This is work for me in `Magento 2.2.0` version, hopefully this will work in `Magento 2.2.1` and other `Magento 2.2x` versions as well.

Comment: Strange but your code exist in Magento 2.3.2
and not working for Android  :(

I replaced if (isIOS && eventType === 'touchend') to if (eventType === 'touchend')

and working correctly.

Seems before Magento release - not checked code and not tested :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is based on lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.js file on 146 line :

```
if (this.isTouchEnabled) {
   this.settings.$element.on('tap', '.fotorama__stage__frame', 
   function () {
    var translate = getTranslate($(this).parents('.fotorama__stage__shaft'));

    if (translate[1] === '0' && !$(this).hasClass('fotorama-video-container')) {
        self.openFullScreen();
        self.settings.$pageWrapper.hide();
    }
   });
}
```

Replace this code with

```
    if (this.isTouchEnabled && this.settings.isFullscreen) {
            this.settings.$element.on('tap', '.fotorama__stage__frame', function () {
                var translate = getTranslate($(this).parents('.fotorama__stage__shaft'));

                if (translate[1] === '0' && !$(this).hasClass('fotorama-video-container')) {
                   self.openFullScreen();
                   self.settings.$pageWrapper.hide();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: The file  lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.js  has already that part of code like that, but starting from the line 153, and it still doesn't work..

Comment: Which Theme is activated for frontend?

Comment: I created a new theme, with the luma files, basically did another folder, copyed luma, and did another one, new name, changed css..

Answer (score 0):

A fixed has been commited to magento:2.2-develop branch. This worked for me
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13268

Comment: Hi @Koen is this fixed in magento2.2.3 CE since i am facing same issue could you please advise