# Magento 2.2.1- Fullscreen image close button not working iOS

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.1, fotorama

When I click on the close icon on an iphone or ipad nothing happens. Hooked the device up to my iMac to debug and there's no errors in the console. Any suggestions?

**Update**

As highlighted below this was an issue with the fotorama plugin and fix is currently on the 2.2-develop branch. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13268

Comment: Can you please upload your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fixed has been commited to magento:2.2-develop branch. This worked for me
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13268

Answer (score 0):

Override `fotorama.js` and replace code as per this solution:- [Magento 2 product gallery doesn't close on iPhone](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207194/magento-2-product-gallery-doesnt-close-on-iphone/231511#231511)